# How to boot XBMC 10.1 ISO on USB via grub?

Tags: boot, grub, iso-image, kodi

I am trying to boot the [XBMC Live image](http://xbmc.org/download/) as an ISO from USB via grub 1.98.

I have a Kubuntu 11.04 image there as well already and it works using the following configuration:

```
menuentry "Kubuntu 11.04 64bit" {
  loopback loop /boot/iso/kubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso
  linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/boot/iso/kubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso noeject noprompt
  initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.gz
}
```

However, if I try to boot XBMC in an analogue way, I always get an error "**Unable to find a medium containing a live file system**".

I found different approaches to install XBMC, but they all are about installing the distribution on USB, or using grub4dos, or unetbootin.

I already found out that XBMC 10.1 is based on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS, so I tried those settings - even though they are quite similar to Kubuntu 11.04.

Finally, the ISO contains a grub configuration as well in `boot/grub/grub.cfg`, but even with those parameters, I get the error above.

My current configuration is the following one:

```
menuentry "xbmc 10.1" {
  loopback loop /boot/iso/xbmc-10.1-live.iso
  linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz video=vesafb boot=live iso-scan/filename=/boot/iso/xbmc-10.1-live.iso xbmc=autostart,nodiskmount splash quiet loglevel=0 persistent quickreboot quickusbmodules notimezone noaccessibility noapparmor noaptcdrom noautologin noxautologin noconsolekeyboard nofastboot nognomepanel nohosts nokpersonalizer nolanguageselector nolocales nonetworking nopowermanagement noprogramcrashes nojockey nosudo noupdatenotifier nouser nopolkitconf noxautoconfig noxscreensaver nopreseed union=aufs
  initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

Any more ideas or any more information I should supply?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the boot loader where the XBMC live file system is located. The live folder should contain files like `filesystem.squashfs`, `filesystem.size` and `filesystem.packages`. Once you've found that folder, add the following argument to your boot configuration:

```
live-media-path={absolute folder path}
```

In my case, the line of code read like this:

```
kernel /XBMC/live/vmlinuz {blah blah more code blah} live-media-path=/XBMC/live

append initrd=/XBMC/live/initrd.img
```

Comment: I am using grub 1.98 and it says `error: unknown command 'kernel'` and `error: unknown command 'append'`.